# PyQT4 TextBrowser Set Text Alighment

Tags: python, text, alignment, pyqt4

I am doing some random choice picker where there's a place to display info user keyed in. (which I used text browser), How do I set the text to be always align center?

```
    self.textBrowser.setText(newList + "\n\nanalyzing in ...")

    QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)

    self.textBrowser.setText(newList + "\n\nanalyzing in ..." + "\n\n       3")
```

Answer (score 0):

`QTextBrowser Class`  Inherits: `QTextEdit`

> QTextEdit::setAlignment(Qt::Alignment)
>
> Sets the alignment of the current paragraph to a. Valid alignments are Qt::AlignLeft, Qt::AlignRight, Qt::AlignJustify and Qt::AlignCenter (which centers horizontally).

Sorry, I have PyQt5:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = 5

        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        
        self.textBrowser.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)  # <-------------
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.print_out)
        timer.start()

    def print_out(self, string="Hello world!"):
        self.textBrowser.append(string + "\n\nanalyzing in ...\n {}".format('----' * self.i))
        self.i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = Win()
    myWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]